# Is it allowed to choose delta first in limit problems?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was studying solved examples of limits of functions of one variable and in each problem epsilon was chosen first then delta was obtained. So, can we choose delta first and obtain epsilon? If we cannot, then what is the reason for choosing epsilon first?

Comment: Look at the definition of a limit. It basically says "for *any* $\varepsilon > 0$ I give you, you must produce a $\delta$ small enough to satisfy this definition." That is, you can't just pick one $\varepsilon$. Your proof must work for *all* positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I suppose if $f$ is constant in a neighborhood of $a$ (excluding $a$ itself), one could choose $\delta$ without caring about $\epsilon$, but this is a trivial case.

Comment: But it is allowed to limit $δ$ first for any value of $ε$. For instance, in many proofs you will find the initial restriction $δ\le 1$, which is reflected in the final result as $δ=\min(1,...)$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of the limit:

> Given a real-valued function $f(x)$ of a real variable and some real number $a$, then we say that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=L$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

As you can see in the definition, the whole point of $\delta$ is to be chosen so that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.  This is why $\epsilon$ needs to be picked first.

Answer (score 0):

If we define

$$\lim^A_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

to mean

> For every $\delta$ there exists an $\epsilon$ such that for all $x$, $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

then

$$\lim^A_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

is true if and only if $f(x)$ is bounded on every interval. That sounds nothing like a limit; it doesn't even have anything to do with $a$ or $L$!

If we define

$$\lim^B_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

to mean

> There exists a $\delta$ such that for every $\epsilon$ and $x$, $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

then that is the same thing as saying there are nonempty intervals $(b,a)$ and $(a,c)$ such that $f(x)$ is the constant function equal to $L$ on both intervals. That also doesn't sound much like a limit.